# i am working on someone project that use a version of react-leaflet that import Map instead MapContainer

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet.draw, react-leaflet-draw

[image: image error link]

I wanna do a task that needs react-leaflet-draw but this error occurred

Does anyone know what should I do except updating the react-leaflet because the project is too big?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.